# React Js Installation Errors in Windows 7

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the problem in installing the reactjs on the localhost. Getting the error of module babel.

One more thing I am following the tutorial from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/. I followed all the steps same to same as given in the installation chapter but still getting the errors.

[image]

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have installed `babel-loader` ?

Comment: Yes, I have installed. I am new in ReactJs. But I can show you my package.json file for better understanding.

{
  "name": "reactApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0"
  }
}

Comment: Can you please try to save the following as dependencies to your project, and check if it solves your issue? `npm install -D babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can I save these dependencies? Could you please don't mind to make edit in the json as I attached in the above reply?

Thanks

Comment: You save them by simply running the command I gave you above. Once you run the command they will be downloaded and also get registered in your `package.json`

Comment: Okay Thanks. So I have to install these packages single or it can be multiple?

Vikash

Comment: You can save them all at once with the command I gave you.

Comment: Hi Mitch Karajohn Thanks for your precious time to solve this issue. It is working now.
Great Thanks! 
Vikash

Comment: Added an answer down below, please mark it as an accepted answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it solved your issue I am posting this here as an answer as well.

Save the following packages as dependencies to your project.

`npm install -D babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015`

This is equal to doing 

`npm install -D babel-core 
npm install -D babel-loader 
npm install -D babel-preset-react 
npm install -D babel-preset-es2015`

Th `-D` arguments saves the packages as `devDependencies` in your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have node and npm install just run these commands to install react.

```
     npm i -g create-react-app
```

I will install react cli for you and you are done.